# Redirecionar após login no Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin-forms

Estou criando um APP com Xamarin Forms, e após entrar com o login e senha recebo os dados da API, vejo que o login foi executado com sucesso pois uso o console.write para imprimir os dados recebidos. 
Estou usando a linha abaixo para redirecionar para um dashboard, porém gera um exception.

await Navigation.PushAsync(new Dashboard());

Como redirecionar para outra página?

Comment: Tente dessa forma: await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Dashboard());

Comment: Qual a exception? Pode ser muita coisa, como por exemplo um problema de excopo no chamada do PushAsync ou um erro no XAML da própria `Dashboard`.